# Fix line chart from drawing off edge

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

I'm using the latest version of the canvasjs.chart and I'm experiencing a situation where data points from the X and Y axis are drawing off the bounds of the canvas( as shown by image below)

[image]

The data is dynamic and can range from 50 to 250000 on display. I tried adding padding but to no avail. What can I do to fix and keep the data points from "falling off" the canvas.

My current options are a merge between

```
{
    height: 190,
    axisY: {
      titleFontSize: 16,
      valueFormatString: "$#,###.##",
    },
    legend:{
      cursor:"pointer",
      verticalAlign: "bottom",
      horizontalAlign: "right"
    }

{
      animationEnabled: true,
      theme: "light2",
      zoomEnabled: true,
      title: {
        text: "All Index (Main Market Net)"
      },
      axisY: {
        title: "Price in JA",
        titleFontSize: 16,
        prefix: "$"
      },
      axisX:{
         valueFormatString:"DD MMM YY"
      }
  }
```